# How do I incorporate Google WebFonts into my phpBB forum?

Tags: phpbb, google-webfonts

I've read somewhere, or at least I thought I did, that by adding the Google WebFont  to the overall_header, that you can use the font-family in your css files(common.css and/or colours.css) but when I did so, nothing changed. I'm not really too sure what .php file it is that I need to add the  to since it looks like the overall_header file isn't working. (I've been modifying the overall_header file in the 'prosilver' theme section fyi, not the 'subsilver' theme section). Any ideas what .php file it is that needs the Google WEbFont link added to it?

Answer (score 0):

all I did was put these two.

common.css in body

```
font-family: 'Alef', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

in overall_header.html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

http://test.damienekitel.com

Shows the font working, purge cache and refresh theme and template.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[Get Started with the Google Fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started)

> This guide explains how to use the Google Fonts API to add fonts to your web pages. You don't need to do any programming; all you have to do is add a special stylesheet link to your HTML document, then refer to the font in a CSS style.